# Specify asset to pay fees in a transfer - Subxt

Tags: subxt, assets

I am doing a transfer in AssetHub and I want to use another asset to pay fees. I have seen an example in JavaScript where it needs to specify the `assetId` in the `signAndSend` function:

```js
await api.tx.balances
    .transfer(address, 100)
    .signAndSend(signer, { assetId: tokenId });
```

How I can do that in Subxt? I checked the example in the Subxt repository on how to send a tx with params([see code](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/subxt/examples/tx_with_params.rs)):

```rs
    // Configure the transaction parameters; we give a small tip and set the
    // transaction to live for 32 blocks from the `latest_block` above.
    let tx_params = Params::new()
        .tip(1_000)
        .mortal(latest_block.header(), 32)
        .build();
```

But is only to add a tip, how can I specify the asset_id I want to use to pay fees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting an asset ID to use in the current release of Subxt (0.31.0), you'd construct extrinsic params like this:

```rust
use subxt::config::substrate::AssetTip;

let tx_params = Params::new()
    .tip(AssetTip::new(1_000).of_asset(123)) // 123 is the asset ID to tip
    .era(Era::Immortal, api.genesis_hash());
```

And then pass these params to one of the functions responsible for submitting a transaction, for instance:

```rust
api.tx().sign_and_submit_then_watch(&some_tx, &from, tx_params).await?
```

The signed extension responsible for requiring fees that can be paid using a different asset ID is `ChargeAssetTxPayment` (chains like Polkadot which have only one token that can be used will instead use the `ChargeTransactionPayment` signed extension, which only asks for a tip amount and not an optional asset ID). This looks like:

```rust
/// Require payment for transaction inclusion and optionally include a tip to gain additional
/// priority in the queue. Allows paying via both `Currency` as well as `fungibles::Balanced`.
///
/// Wraps the transaction logic in [`pallet_transaction_payment`] and extends it with assets.
/// An asset ID of `None` falls back to the underlying transaction payment logic via the native
/// currency.
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Clone, Eq, PartialEq, TypeInfo)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
pub struct ChargeAssetTxPayment<T: Config> {
    #[codec(compact)]
    tip: BalanceOf<T>,
    asset_id: Option<ChargeAssetIdOf<T>>,
}
```

The comment (and code that I skimmed over) suggests that if we provide an `asset_id` that is not `None` here, then that asset ID will be used to pay both transaction fees and any tip that's given. If the `asset_id` is `None`, then we fall back to using the native chain token to pay the fees and tip.